# Strange delete behaviour while using NSFetchedResultsController

Tags: ios, uitableview, core-data, ios7, nsfetchedresultscontroller

I'm using this code to delete a row in my `NSFetchedResultsController`. The animation for the row deletion works perfectly except for the Delete sign. The sign stays completely visible until the row is faded and then suddenly disappears. But everything should fade including the delete sign, as in other apps. What am I missing again?

Here are all relevant methods (and all are called correctly and I've tried different animation types, but didn't work either).

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle
forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Update the data model according to edit actions delete or insert.
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        [self.managedObjectContext deleteObject:[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

        //Adjust the indices of the remaining entries
        NSArray *fetchedResults = [[self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects] copy];

        int i = 1;
        for (MainCategory *fetchedResult in fetchedResults)
        {
            fetchedResult.position = [NSNumber numberWithInt:i++];
        }
    }
}

- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
   didChangeObject:(id)anObject
       atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
     forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type
      newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
    if(!self.reordering){
        if (!self.suspendAutomaticTrackingOfChangesInManagedObjectContext)
        {
            switch(type)
            {
                case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;

                case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;

                case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                    [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;

                case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    [self.tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ok after 10 tries managed to make a screenshot :-)
[image]

Edit: Here you see the problem: The delete action happens, the to be deleted row fades away while the Delete sign stays completely visible and doesn't fade. Only after the row is completely faded away, the delete sign disappears immediately.

**EDIT 2:**
 I've narrowed it down. If I comment this loop with the new calculation of all positions, the delete works as nicely as expected. But I need to update these positions don't I? Or how would you do that?

Comment: Screenshots of this weird behavior could be useful...

Comment: And why are you copying fetched objects? Any reason?

Comment: I have one attribute position in my table (position of this particular category in my current table, according to the sort chosen by the user). So if a category gets deleted all other positions need to be updated. Trying to make a screenshot

Comment: But why you are copying the objects you have fetched? I guess it's not necessary...

Comment: But the for loop is necessary isn't it? so I should just write for(MainCategory *fetchedResult in [self.fetchedResultsController fetchedObjects])?

Comment: I think so. Any reason you put it?

Comment: Hm not necessarily..programmed that section long time ago, probably a mistake. thx for the hint, removed it. :) But the delete problem still remains.

Comment: Based on the image, could you describe better the behavior? Please edit your question doing that.

Comment: Ok I've edited my question and I've narrowed it down. If I comment this new calculation of all positions, the delete works as nicely as expected. But I need to update these positions don't I? Or how would you do that?

Answer (score 1):

I would try to recalculate the position in `- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller` method. Just to be sure all is finished. Otherwise  I have no ideas where to do it. Maybe there is a suitable notification for listening to changes in the context but I'm not aware of.

Obviously,

> But I need to update these positions don't I?

It depends on your needs. If you don't do it, no one will update them. But if you use the `position` attribute to order the items, you need to recalculate again for each fetched element.

So,

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    [self.tableView endUpdates];

    if(self.recalculatePosition) { // this means that somewhere you set that bool to YES

        // suspend the tracking of changes before???

        self.recalculatePosition = NO; 

        // for loop here...
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately didn't work. But I've thought about it. Since I use this position only for the sort I don't see any use in keeping it perfectly accurate. Of course after reordering I have to update it. But not after deletion. Shouldn't be a problem if a number is missing, since the sort is still valid.

Answer (score 1):

Recalculating your position is updating the fetched objects, which is firing off more updates to your table, which is interfering with the animation.

If you need the position property to support manual ordering, then when you are recalculating it you should suppress updates coming through the FRC. It looks like you already have some state in place to allow that, so it should be fairly simple.

Comment: Yeah tried that, but then the delete doesn't happen at all. I guess I just go with accepting some missing numbers, which will be filled again after reordering. So the sort isn't affected if some are missing and I'm happy. :-)